# xamarin forms initialization error in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I keep getting this error forms exists both in uap and tablets exception for xamarin form initialization, the exact error`Error CS0433  The type 'Forms' exists in both 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 
'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Tablet, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`. Versions for UWP are target `Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)` min version`Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, after a lot of reading and trying several posts and suggestions, I figured out that I had `Xamarin.Forms.Windows` added to the UWP project. Once I removed it, I was able to build it. Since my project was initially targeted `Android` platform only, had selected `Shared Project` from Visual Studio's project setup window (project type `Visual C#->Cross-Platform`) and later added `Windows Universal Blank App` to support/test/debug on `Windows` (had this plugin added for testing windows Ui features). Since I had both `Xamarin.Forms` and `Xamarin.Forms.Windows` it was complaining.